# My Toilet Keeps Making Sounds Like It Is Filling Up Every 3 Minutes

Tags: water, toilet

What is causing my toilets to kick on every other minute? It's not flushing - it sounds like the water is filling up. Does this make the electric bill higher?

Comment: Won't affect the electric bill. But it will affect the water bill.

Comment: It will if they are on a well.

Answer (score 4):

Since you aren't seeing water all over the place, your flapper is leaking a small amount of water which is causing the float to drop to a level (apparently every 3 minutes) where it detects the water is low, so it fills the tank back up. If you aren't familiar with the mechanics of the float/flapper system in toilets, take the tank lid off and flush it a few times; it's pretty easy to see what it is doing. You might be able to slight adjust the flapper by just running your thumb around the part that seats or you might need to replace it (it's cheap and easy).

As far as electric bill, it won't make your electric bill higher if you live in the city since water is fed by gravity, but in the country where water is pumped from underground, it would. The bigger concern would be water cost if you are in the city.

Comment: My flapper went off center over the hole. I fixed the problem by adding a 1/4" piece of neoprene stopper, sliced halfway through with a razorblade on the right side of the flapper pivot. Flapper is now centered, and problem is gone 5 months now.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a leak on the flush flapper (or whatever mechanism lets the water into the bowl), it's slow enough to not notice, but when the float gets low, it has to refill the tank.